# PROTRACTOR: Right click on link and open in NEW TAB

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor

**TestCase:** Right click on link element and open in NEW TAB or NEW WINDOW.

I could able to right click on the element using the below code. But not sure how to select the option of "**OPEN Link in NEW TAB**".

**TRIED:**

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(rightClickEle).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

Comment: Here's several options you might consider...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536948/protractor-button-click-and-open-page-in-new-tab

Comment: @CaptainKidd , No You dont find solution to "RIGHT CLICK and Open in NEW TAB " in the source you are referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I sorted out the solution to "RIGHT CLICK AND OPEN IN NEWTAB".

```js
var rightClickEle = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'linkA')]"));
browser.actions().mouseMove(rightClickEle).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
browser.actions().mouseMove(rightClickEle).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click().perform();
browser.actions().mouseMove(rightClickEle).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click().keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform();
```