# How to do right mouse click in protractor chrome?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, chromedriver

After referring to: [PROTRACTOR: Right click on link and open in NEW TAB](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/34674/protractor-right-click-on-link-and-open-in-new-tab)

I tried below code :

```js
    describe('Right click', function () {
    
    
      it('test {Regression} {Sanity} {Sanity}', async function () {
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    
        await browser.get("https://www.onlinemictest.com/mouse-test/");
        let b=await browser.getProcessedConfig()
        console.log(b.capabilities.browserName)
        var rightClickEle = await $('.webcam-2-icon_');
        await browser.actions().mouseMove(rightClickEle).perform();
        await browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
        await browser.sleep(7000)
    });
    });
```

But it's not doing right-click, its always going for left click. Could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5271

There is known bug

The work around is to disable w3c protocol in your config file:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome' ,

'chromeOptions': {
//args:['version']
w3c: false
//},//11 or 'safari'*/
}},
```

**For microsoft webdriver: (Edge)**

Create a bat (say a.bat) file with below content (assuming the driver is in c)

```
C:\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe %* --jwp
```

Now pass this as the dge webdriver using jvmArgs

```
exports.config = {

specs: ['spec.js'],

//seleniumAddress:"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: {
    port:5000,
  jvmArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=a.bat'],
},


capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge' ,
},
```